# PlaneGeometry diagonal issue THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I have problem with creating Mesh with PlaneGeometry. I used MeshBasicMaterial and at first I have this definition of geometry:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height);
```

After that, when I generate Mesh, everything is OK. But in some elements I have to change geometry vertices before create mesh, so I do following:

```
geometry.dynamic = true; 
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
$.each(newVertices, function(index, value) {
  geometry.vertices[index].x = value.x;    
  geometry.vertices[index].y = value.y;    
  geometry.vertices[index].z = value.z;    
});

geometry.computeFaceNormals();
```

And finally create Mesh, it´s fine. But when create this geometry, It seems to be like diagonal broken as you can see on picture, where black is my created mesh and white texture seems like diagonal broken.

[image]

Where can be a problem?

**EDIT**
I found, that it´s because geometry is with triangles, and my material is square. So when I change coordinates of vertices, It damage material. Is there possible to change geometry to square? Or how to fix that?

Comment: UV coordinates problem maybe.

Comment: And how I can fix that?